# Django3: Dynamic queryset function allocation performance

Tags: django, performance, django-queryset

i am just experimenting on how to 'dynamically allocate queryset functions' and i would like to know the performance issues i might face later on.

My querysets are working perfectly but i am a little skeptical about them.

Please have a look at my code:

**settings.py:**

```
...
TODO_PRIORITY = (
     ('LOW', 'Low'),
     ('MEDIUM', 'Medium'),
     ('HIGH', 'High'),
)
...
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils import timezone
from .manager import TodoManager
from django.conf import settings

User = get_user_model()

TODO_PRIORITY = getattr(settings, 'TODO_PRIORITY', None)
assert TODO_PRIORITY is not None, "Your settings file is missing `TODO_PRIORITY` variable"
assert isinstance(TODO_PRIORITY, tuple), "`TODO_PRIORITY` must be a tuple"

# Create your models here.
class Todo(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('start_time',)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="todos")
    content = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)

    start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)

    priority = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=TODO_PRIORITY, default="MEDIUM")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = TodoManager()

    @property
    def todo_id(self):
        return self.id
```

**manager.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings

now = timezone.now()
today = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
tomorrow = today + timezone.timedelta(days=1)

TODO_PRIORITY = getattr(settings, 'TODO_PRIORITY', None)
assert TODO_PRIORITY is not None, "Your settings file is missing `TODO_PRIORITY` variable."
assert isinstance(TODO_PRIORITY, tuple), "`TODO_PRIORITY` must be a tuple."

class TodoQueryset(models.query.QuerySet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for priority in TODO_PRIORITY:
            self.add__fn(priority)

    def add__fn(self, object):
        assert isinstance(object, tuple), '`TODO_PRIORITY` object must be a tuple.'
        fn_name = object[1].lower()

        def fn():
            return self.filter(priority=object[0].upper(), start_time__gte=today)

        setattr(self, fn_name, fn)


class TodoManager(models.Manager):
    _queryset_class = TodoQueryset
```

> UPDATE 0

i have noticed that the `__init__()` runs multiple times, how can i avoid that ?

=> i have asked around and it seems like a normal behaviour because django uses `filter()` then `get()`

> UPDATE 1

i have finally manager to find a way to auto create class methods and i'll post the answer in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sniffing around i have realised that my `add__fn()` function will be called everytime `TodoQuerySet` is called so i have decided to move `add__fn()` outside of the class and add functions from there.

**manager.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings

now = timezone.now()
today = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
tomorrow = today + timezone.timedelta(days=1)

TODO_PRIORITY = getattr(settings, 'TODO_PRIORITY', None)
assert TODO_PRIORITY is not None, "Your settings file is missing `TODO_PRIORITY` variable."
assert isinstance(TODO_PRIORITY, tuple), "`TODO_PRIORITY` must be a tuple."

class TodoQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
     pass

def add__fn(object):
    assert isinstance(object, tuple), '`TODO_PRIORITY` object must be a tuple.'
    fn_name = object[1].lower()

    def fn(self):
            return self.filter(priority=object[0].upper(), start_time__gte=today)

    setattr(TodoQuerySet, fn_name, fn)

for priority in TODO_PRIORITY:
    add__fn(priority)

TodoQueryset = TodoQuerySet
```

**models.py**

```
from .manager import TodoQueryset

class Todo(...):

    objects = TodoQueryset.as_manager()
```